# should i be able to use yaml with spring ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration-files

i'm trying to use spring's cool ConfigurationProperties feature to automagically load config values into a bean. i have been able to get it to work with a properties file, but when i try the same thing with a yaml file, it doesn't work.

i've seen similar examples posted, but it doesn't seem to be working for me:

**`TestBean.java:`**

```
package com.kerz;

public class TestBean {
  private String value;

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public TestBean(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

**`JavaTestConfiguration.java:`**

```
package com.kerz;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="pre")
public class JavaTestConfiguration {

  @NotNull
  String testBeanValue;

  public String getTestBeanValue() {
    return testBeanValue;
  }

  public void setTestBeanValue(String testBeanValue) {
    this.testBeanValue = testBeanValue;
  }

  @Bean
  TestBean testBean() {
    return new TestBean(testBeanValue);
  }
}
```

**`JavaTestConfigurationTest.java:`**

```
package com.kerz;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JavaTestConfiguration.class})
//@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@EnableConfigurationProperties({JavaTestConfiguration.class})
public class JavaTestConfigurationTest {

  @Autowired
  TestBean testBean;

  @Test
  public void shouldWork() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("testBean", "test-value", testBean.getValue());
  }
}
```

**`application.properties:`**

`pre.testBeanValue=test-value`

**`application.yml:`**

```
pre:
  testBeanValue: test-value
```

here is [a link to the full sample](https://github.com/tony-kerz/boot-scratch/tree/e1f9dac9668316601bd20d55dfa65a255ed446d9)

Comment: You've got both application.properties and application.yml files configuring the same property. One of them has to win. Have you tried it with just the YAML file?

Comment: thx @AndyWilkinson, only one of those should be in play at a time. notice how i commented out one of the `@PropertySource` lines above?

Comment: ConfigurationProperties (and i think also YAML for configuration files) are part of Spring Boot, not the Spring Framework itself. However you don't use any Spring Boot annotations in your test. I'm not sure if it's intended to work in a non-Spring-Boot environment. Maybe Andy can comment on that. I would expect that with the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)` annotation on your test and the Application.class as Spring Boot application class it could work.

Comment: @dunni, i'm using `@EnableConfigurationProperties` which comes from spring-boot, which seems like it should work, but ya never kno (without a deep dive into the source code :)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing `Configuration` class with `Properties` class which is a harder setup to make work. The simplest way to fix it is to split those to like so:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="pre")
public class JavaTestConfigurationProperties {

  @NotNull
  String testBeanValue;

  public String getTestBeanValue() {
    return testBeanValue;
  }

  public void setTestBeanValue(String testBeanValue) {
    this.testBeanValue = testBeanValue;
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({JavaTestConfigurationProperties.class})
public class JavaTestConfiguration {
  @Bean
  TestBean testBean(JavaTestConfigurationProperties properties) {
    return new TestBean(properties.getTestBeanValue());
  }
}
```

And then use it i.e.:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JavaTestConfiguration.class})
public class JavaTestConfigurationTest {
}
```

Comment: i can see the organizational appeal of separating out config and properties, but i am witnessing the same behavior of the yaml props not being picked up...?

Comment: Is it because only properties getting picked, not yml files?